# How do I get postfix and dovecot to connect to outside domains?

Tags: server, email, postfix, gmail

I have been trying, for the last few hours now, to get dovecot and postfix to send emails to services like GMail and a web hosting email. I know (and hope) that they are not blocking my server. Its a Google Compute Engine server running Ubuntu 14.10, and I've opened the proper ports (25, 143, and 993), but it still can't connect. I just ran the command:

```
echo "test email text." | mail -s "test email" harlydavidsen@gmail.com
```

It tried to send it. Here is the output of `tail -f /var/logs/mail.log`:

```
Mar 21 23:09:01 realitysoftware postfix/qmgr[5928]: 44C63413ED: from=<root@realitysoftware.no-ip.org>, size=742, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 21 23:09:01 realitysoftware postfix/local[6815]: 44C63413ED: to=<root@realitysoftware.no-ip.org>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar 21 23:09:01 realitysoftware postfix/qmgr[5928]: 44C63413ED: removed
Mar 21 23:14:55 realitysoftware postfix/qmgr[5928]: 037D741394: from=<EthinP@realitysoftware.no-ip.org>, size=387, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 21 23:15:25 realitysoftware postfix/smtp[6942]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.201.27]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 21 23:15:25 realitysoftware postfix/smtp[6942]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c01::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar 21 23:15:55 realitysoftware postfix/smtp[6942]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.208.27]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 21 23:15:55 realitysoftware postfix/smtp[6942]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c0a::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar 21 23:15:55 realitysoftware postfix/smtp[6942]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400c:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar 21 23:15:55 realitysoftware postfix/smtp[6942]: 037D741394: to=<harlydavidsen@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=537, delays=476/0.01/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400c:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

I am trying to set up an email service with Round Cube version 1.1.1, if that helps. I have php5 version PHP 5.5.12-2ubuntu4.3 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2015 20:50:26) and PHP 5.5.12-2ubuntu4.3 (built: Mar 16 2015 20:50:26); Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies,    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

I have tried and tried again, time and time again, to fix this issue, but have not been able to at all. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google compute engine does not allow sending email - but offfers a free relay service thru sendgrid:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail